# Rails Wiselinks & Angular : How can I make the angular code load after the page loads?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, wiselinks

When I use the `data-push` the Angular code shows up as this `{{user.name }}` How can I make the page request so the Angular code gets triggered ?
`Turbolinks` is a bad mix with Angular and jQuery on Rails, I took it out, because it caused so much trouble, I decided not to go there and use `Wiselinks` instead.
This is what I'm doing:

I have the `@users` being passed to `$resource` to the data to Angular side:

```
App.factory('User', [
  '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/users/:id.json', {
      id: '@id'
    });
  }
]);
```

and I have the template working when I enter the Page `localhost:3000/users` as address however when I click the link with `data-push` enabled:

```
<a href="<%= users_path %>" data-push="true">Users</a>
```

It only loads to the console and the empty Angular template shows up in the view

```
 {{user.name}}
```

from the `ng-repeat`

Again I know this is a bad mixture, but this is the only way I know to make this Web app like style work and I feel like I'm hitting bottleneck and I missing something, I guess the page Have to be LOADED without push, wiselinks and turbolinks one way or another.
Is that true ? please say no.

Code Update:

`app.js`
`window.App = angular.module('UsersApp', ['ngResource'])`

`user_ctrl.js`

`

```
App.controller('UserCtrl', [
  '$scope', 'User','$compile', function($scope, User,$compile) {
    $scope.users = User.query();

  }
]);

user.js
App.factory('User', [
  '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/users/:id.json', {
      id: '@id'
    });
  }
]);
```

Now in the view I have this inside `users/index.html.erb`

```
<div  class="row" ng-controller="UserCtrl"  ng-cloak ng-app="UsersApp">
  <div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:searchText">

                        <strong>{{ user.full_name }}</strong>

</div>
</div>
```

`

In the actuall code, `ng-cloak ng-app="UsersApp"` is defined on the `body`

Comment: Can you show us your angular controller and a bit more of your view? Wiselinks is very similar to Turbolinks, so I would assume the problems you had with turbolinks will also occur with wiselinks.

Comment: I understand it's mandatory for you to use wisekinks right? The usual is to remove turbolinks and forget about wiselinks when you're using a js framework... Did you see this article? http://blog.berylliumwork.com/2013/08/wiselinks-with-angularjs.html

Comment: @mlainez,That is how I realized I can use wiselinks, never knew what it was, I was using turbolinks all the time :)! I only need a solution to manipulate the objects in the front without sending server requests.